# passing variables from one jsp page to another?

Tags: java, jsp, error-handling

I am trying to pass variable from one jsp page to another . Here is my code :

```
<%for(i=0;i<30;i++)
            { //id[i]=test4query.arr[i];
                out.println("<a href='final.jsp?itemId=<%=mailid[i]%&gt'>"+id[i]+"</a>");
%>
```

I am using request.get parameter to obtain the value...

```
<%=request.getParameter("itemId") %>
```

But the output is null and I get this error in console

```
Character decoding failed. Parameter [itemId] with value [<3C%=mailid[0]%%3E] has been ignored
```

I am using &gt because as soon as I use **%>** it detect it as jsp character and not as normal character under quotes?What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `println` to look like this, because the variable substitution won't work as you have it. You need to use string concatenation.

```
out.println("<a href='final.jsp?itemId=" + mailid[i] + "'>" + id[i] + "</a>");
```

Note this doesn't handle URL encoding of the `mailid`, I assume you've handled that.